# Swift The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: json, swift

I am new to swift and trying to figure out how to parse JSON to a struct. I am trying to get an image from NASA Mar's Rover Photos.I am trying to follow tutorials online, but can't seem to fix this issue. What am I doing wrong here?

error:

Fatal error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

```
import Foundation

class API {
    class func getImage(_ onSucessus: @escaping ([LatestPhoto]) -> ()){
        Constrant.session.dataTask(with: Constrant.request){(data, res, err) in
            guard let data = data, err == nil else{
                fatalError()
            }
            do{
                let apod = try Constrant.decoder.decode([LatestPhoto].self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    onSucessus(apod)
                }
            }
            catch{
                fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            
        }.resume()
        
    }
}
```

Struct

```
struct LatestPhoto: Identifiable, Codable{
    let id = UUID()
    let imgSrc: String
    let earthDate: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case imgSrc = "img_src"
        case earthDate = "earth_date"
      
    }
}
```

JSON

```
{
  "latest_photos": [
    {
      "id": 839114,
      "sol": 3127,
      "camera": {
        "id": 20,
        "name": "FHAZ",
        "rover_id": 5,
        "full_name": "Front Hazard Avoidance Camera"
      },
      "img_src": "https://mars.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/03127/opgs/edr/fcam/FRB_675093431EDR_F0880366FHAZ00302M_.JPG",
      "earth_date": "2021-05-23",
      "rover": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Curiosity",
        "landing_date": "2012-08-06",
        "launch_date": "2011-11-26",
        "status": "active"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 839115,
      "sol": 3127,
      "camera": {
        "id": 20,
        "name": "FHAZ",
        "rover_id": 5,
        "full_name": "Front Hazard Avoidance Camera"
      },
      "img_src": "https://mars.nasa.gov/msl-raw-images/proj/msl/redops/ods/surface/sol/03127/opgs/edr/fcam/FLB_675093431EDR_F0880366FHAZ00302M_.JPG",
      "earth_date": "2021-05-23",
      "rover": {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Curiosity",
        "landing_date": "2012-08-06",
        "launch_date": "2011-11-26",
        "status": "active"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON format doesn't quite match what you're trying to decode. You need a wrapper for the `latest_photos` array at the root of your JSON object.

For example:

```
struct LatestPhotosWrapper: Codable {
    let latestPhotos: [LatestPhoto]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case latestPhotos = "latest_photos"
    }
}
```

```
let apod = try JSONDecoder().decode(LatestPhotosWrapper.self, from: data)
```

(Rather than providing a `CodingKey`, you can also look into the built-in systems for converting from snake case: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/keydecodingstrategy/convertfromsnakecase)

Also, you may want to print the `error` and not just the `error.localizedDescription` -- you can get a better picture of what's going on. For example, with your original code, you get:

> Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.

Finally, you might check out app.quicktype.io -- you can paste in your JSON and get correct Swift structs pre-built for you.

Comment: It works now. Thank you so much for your help.